# How to store Hindi text in MySQL from Android?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm getting ?????? in MySQL instead of Hindi text. I have following code to get Hindi text from edittext and send to PHP page which is to store the my text.

***My Activity***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     EditText s;
     Button b1;
      private JSONObject jsonObject=null;
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
           ProgressDialog dialog = null;


         @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        s=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
       Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "akshar.ttf");               

     s.setTypeface(tf);


     b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+s.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new GetAllPosts().execute();
        }
    });
}


private class GetAllPosts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            List<NameValuePair> params   = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text",""+s.getText()));

            jsonObject = sh.makeServiceCall("http://192.168.24.12/temp/v1/temp.php", ServiceHandler.POST, params);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: How did you check that you have ?????? in mysql?

Comment: Endode string to UTF-8 before send...

Comment: ya... i have checked... i m getting ?????? in mysql

Comment: @dhawal..... Its not working... i have use ** new String(s.getText().toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")** to convert

Comment: @Vinayak Patil : use MySql's NVARCHAR data type, which supports multi-ligual..

Comment: @Hardy: ya i have try that also.... Even i have set Collation to utf8_general_ci which is supported for all languages

Comment: @Vinayak ; well i am working with a Web-application, in which i have to Support multilingual support. I have just Change data type of Column and i am able to Store any Languages.
> I think there should be mistake in Code.

Comment: @hardy... Its working with web...but i want with android

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the encoding and collation of you MySQL's table. We are also using MySQL for our android app and storing text in different languages along with smileys

```
ALTER TABLE `student` CHANGE `student_name` `student_name` VARCHAR(50)  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 ;
```

`utf8mb4` will work for you.